# Java - Are all instance objects? Are all objects instances?

Tags: java, oop, object, instance

I think I have read some about this topic but just let me put it clear:

I ask this to differentiate a little more "object" and "instance", although in Oracle Java tutorial I haven't seen the word "instance". I think the tutorial author avoided this expression intendedly.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

But, inspired by some other questions here, I think there are two questions which will end this dispute:

> Is every instance considered an object?

(I guess is)

and,

> Is every object in Java, or in OOP, considered an instance?

(I guess no, because I think "instance" are "concrete object instantiated from a class". If an object is not constructed from instantiation, it's not an instance. However correct me if I am wrong).

In my understanding, "object" come from OOP where we see each and every concrete thing as an abstract concept, named "object". And, "instance" come from "instantiation", means "the result of a process of concretion from some class, which is a prototype.", which I have mentioned above. They are concepts with different origins but at last, in practical situations, often refer to the same thing.

If the answer to these two questions are undoubtful "YES", then they are the same. Again, correct me if I have a logical error here.

PS:

When adding tags, I see that definitions in tags of "instance" and "object" are similar.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, an instance is a representation (unique) of an Object.